# Bulk edit userPrincipalName

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I batch-created several hundred AD users. On inspecting, their `userPrincipalName` turned out as such:

```
joesmith@foo.bar,DC=net
```

The FQDN is `foo.bar.net` in this instance. I need the name to be corrected to:

```
joesmith@foo.bar.net
```

Is there a way to do this in bulk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. presuming foo.bar.net is a valid UPN suffix (check in AD Domains and Trusts) you can use a combination of Get-Aduser and Set-aduser in powershell.
   For example:

   `get-aduser -filter * | Set-aduser -UserPrincipalName "foo.bar.net"`

This would change the userprincipal name of all AD Users, using different filters will allow you to select just the users you need.

2. Download ADMODIFY.NET from:
   https://admodify.codeplex.com/ which is a tool for making bulk AD changes.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to split the name at the @ symbol and add the new suffix rather than just setting he new UPN to "foo.bar.net"